# Did Darth Vader ever see Ahsoka again?

Tags: star-wars

I was just wondering if he ever did see his padawan again after ROTS. Don't tell me about Rebels. And did they fight when they met?

Comment: Rebels is the answer - you can't reject it in your question :)

Comment: Did you mean "don't spoil Rebels for me" when you said "don't tell me about Rebels"?

Answer (score 14):

I'm going to tell you about *Rebels*; sorry. As far as I know, there are no clues in any other canon sources (although I haven't read the canon novel *Tarkin*).

It's heavily implied that he never saw Ahsoka after becoming Darth Vader. In the season 2 opener of *Star Wars Rebels*, Kanan and Ahsoka reach out with the Force, trying to sense their Sith Lord foe (who we know as Darth Vader):

Vader's response?

> **Vader:** The apprentice lives.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 2 Episode 1: "The Siege of Lothal"</sup>

And during a conference with the Emperor:

> **Vader:** I believe the apprentice of Anakin Skywalker lives and is in league with the rebels.
>
> **Emperor:** Are you certain?
>
> **Vader:** It was her.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 2 Episode 1: "The Siege of Lothal"</sup>

What's more, Ahsoka is clearly shocked and traumatised by the experience, much more so than Kanan is. While we might chalk this up to being an out-of-practice Jedi confronting a Sith Lord at the height of his power, she acts cagey later, when asked about him:

> **Ahsoka:** I wanted to ask about the Sith Lord you encountered on Lothal.
>
> **Kanan:** You know we encountered an Inquisitor before, but this was nothing like that. The fear... the anger... the hate... you felt it. I haven't felt a presence like that since...
>
> **Ahsoka:** The Clone Wars.
>
> **Kanan:** Yeah.
>
> **Ezra:** Ahsoka, do you know who or what he is?
>
> **Ahsoka:** *[pauses]* No, I don't.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 2 Episode 1: "The Siege of Lothal"</sup>

Although we can't explicitly confirm this, it seems likely that Ahsoka wouldn't have been as shocked if she had previously encountered Vader.

To answer the second question; they fight in a manner of speaking. They're in the middle of a ship-to-ship firefight, but aren't duelling directly. Your mileage may vary.

Vader and Ahsoka did finally meet, and duel, in the *Rebels* season 2 finale "Twilight of the Apprentice":

[image]

And later in the episode, she confirms his true identity after getting a glimpse of his face under the mask:

[image]

Comment: Needs more Rebels. Also, a simple video.

Comment: @Axelrod There you go; just for you

Comment: @JasonBaker Good, good. Let the hate flow *through* you. I can't wait to see what they do to tie up the loose ends of literally having a dozen living jedi running around.

Comment: @Axelrod You mean like the EU? That turned out....I was going to say "okay," but I couldn't type it with a straight face

Comment: @JasonBaker Too many chefs, not enough kitchen. Now we have few enough chefs that you'd think these sorts of things wouldn't turn up.

Comment: the novel 'Tarkin' only contains three references to Tano - all relate to Tarkin's dealings with her in the Clone Wars (as seen in the TV show). Novel 'Lords of the Sith' has one instance - Vader has a fleeting memory that he quickly suppresses.

Comment: I think the OP meant "don't spoil Rebels for me" when they said "don't tell me about Rebels", so maybe hide some of the Rebels spoilers. :)

Comment: @RedCaio What spoilers? Except possibly for Ahsoka being alive (which is presupposed by the question itself), none of the information given above is particularly pivotal to either the plot or character arcs on the show

Comment: Video links are dead